As known, spark structured streaming support that stream join static, but how to refresh the static data when the static data changed
In my spark structured streaming application, the static data is updated per day. But after the application started, the static data in the spark application memory is never updated.
It caused that the result from the second day is incorrect.
anyone knows how to fix that.
